# How do I enable a static time but still have dynamic date?

Tags: excel, date, time, format

Would anyone be so kind to suggest any methods of allowing a change in date while maintaining the time?

So example, Cell A1 has [3-Feb 2020 07:45:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e2uR.png)

I would like to format/fix it such that when i enter any other date for example [8-Feb 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDYQE.png) it will automatically be shown as 8-Feb 2020 07:45:00.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format Cell on this format as mentioned below.

`dd-mm-yyyy "07:45:00"`

***Screenshot:***

[image]